# register a DLL object that references System.Web to be used on SQL CLR

Tags: sql-server, sqlclr

I have a Class Library that uses System.Web to access web services and plan to return the XML back to the SQL stored procedure via SQL CLR.

I'm trying to register the DLL but it kept on looking for either the System.Drawing or System.Web. I tried registering the System.Web but it either prompted me with 'There is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'internal' to run this query.' or with 'unable to access file'.

here's my script:

```
create assembly [System.Drawing]
authorization dbo
from 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Drawing.dll'
with permission_set = unsafe

create assembly SystemWeb
authorization dbo
from 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Web.dll'
with permission_set = unsafe
Go

CREATE ASSEMBLY TestCheckEncounters 
AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
FROM 'C:\APICLR\ClientName.Api.MyCLR.dll'
WITH PERMISSION_SET = unsafe;

GO
```